How to update values from null to 0 dynamically?
Input:



Name
Maths
Science




Dena
95



Karan
90
97


Jack





We need to update values from null to 0 dynamically in KDB qsql.
I'd like to use a functional qsql query in KDB.
Expected output:



Name
Maths
Science




Dena
95
0


Karan
90
97


Jack
0
0



This query works for the above example:
show t: flip `Name`Maths`Science!((`Dena; `Karansingh; `Jack); (95 90 0N); (0N 97 0N))

But it hardcodes the subject (maths and science). I don't want to hardcode the subjects in the query since there might be different subjects in the future (like history and computer). How can I do it dynamically?

Relevant functional q-sql:
![t;();0b;{x!(^;0),/:x}`Maths`Science]

Or using @ without q-sql:
@[t;`Maths`Science;0^]

You haven't posted an example query, but if you ever need help working out what you need in functional q-sql then parse can be helpful:
q)parse"update 0^Maths,0^Science from t"
!
`t
()
0b
`Maths`Science!((^;0;`Maths);(^;0;`Science))

Both of these methods allow for variable column names.

Just one small side note adding to Thomas' answer, you need to pass the table as a symbol (call by name) if you want to make the change persistent (see below)

@AlexanderUnterrainer-DefconQ - For future reference, it's better to provide a link to an answer than saying see below, answers are not in the same order for every user

Leaning on the existing answers, and assuming you want to amend numeric columns, you could do something like:
t:@[t;;0^] exec c from meta[t] where t="j"


Just one small side note adding to Thomas' answer, you need to pass the table as a symbol (call by name) if you want to make the change persistent
![`t;();0b;{x!(^;0),/:x}MathsScience] 
or 
@[`t;Maths`Science;0^] 

